# php getting lines of text from a text file based on a # delimiter at the beginning of each sentence

Tags: php, html

I have a text file

test.txt

and in the file it has lines that begin with '#'

## example

#this is a test

#this is another test

this is not a test

When I run my php script I need it to only grab the lines with the '#' and then remove it so it doesn't show in the echo.

## So the output would be....

this is a test

this is another test

I'm just learning php but this is what I have... It reads one line...

```
<?php

$f=fopen("alertmon_user.txt", "r");

// is this where I need to set the conditions?
echo fgets($f);

fclose($f);

?>
```

What can I add to this to make this work? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file line by line and check if line starts with `#`.

```
$handle = fopen("alertmon_user.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if(substr($line, 0, 1) === "#") {
            //process line here
            echo $line . "</br>"; // add </br> for new line
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

**Update : To remove # from `line`.**

If you want to remove `#` from line then use `substr` method.

for example.

```
$updatedLine = substr($line, 1, strlen($line));
echo $updatedLine . "</br>";
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: I never thought I'd thank a Virus for helping me. :) Thank you it is perfect. Where did you learn this? Can you recommend a book or course that will help me with php?

Comment: one more question would you use the /n for new line or </br> to get new lines?

Comment: never mind i did this and it works, echo $line."<br>";.. any ideas on how to remove the # once it's done it's job though...